# Deepsleep ESP8266 Thing

Tags: esp8266

I have been trying to get my ESP8266 Thing to go to sleep. Power LED has been disconnected. Problem is that the current consumption is initially (briefly) ~78 uA, but *nearly* always jumps up to ~540 uA for the remainder of the sleep duration. See below. It's as though something is waking up when it shouldn't. Has anyone else experienced this? Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

```
#include <Ticker.h> // Ticker can periodically call a function
Ticker blinker; // Ticker object called blinker.

int ledPin = 5; // LED is attached to ESP8266 pin 5.
uint8_t ledStatus = 0; // Flag to keep track of LED on/off status
int counter = 0; // Count how many times we've blinked

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); // Set LED pin (5) as an output
  blinker.attach(0.25, blink); // Ticker on blink function, call every 250ms
}

void loop() 
{

}

void blink()
{
  if (ledStatus)
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  else
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  ledStatus = (ledStatus + 1) % 2; // Flip ledStatus

  if (counter++ > 20) // If we've blinked 20 times
    ESP.deepSleep(60000000, WAKE_RF_DEFAULT); // Sleep for 60 seconds
    //ESP.deepSleep(60000000); // Sleep for 60 seconds
    delay(10);
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the longest ESP8266 sleep time is only in the minutes (far less than an hour).  So, is saving about 500 uAmps between wake-ups add up to much when compared to the average current over, say, an hour?